# Explorer Right Click Context Menu Items Missing

Tags: windows-xp, shell, windows-explorer, extension, context-menu

OS: Windows XP Service Pack 2
When I right click on a file/folder most of the third party context menu items are missing.
These are the items like 7zip , Unlocker, Winamp ... which adds entry to right click context menu.
What could be wrong?
I checked HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers and they don't seem to have items added with any of these third party installs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need them I would start uninstalling the programs that put the shell extensions in.  Aftermarket shell extensions can wreak havoc.  Smearp has a good idea too but I am not familiar with that product (it does look good though).

Also, when you have shell issues re-installing the latest service pack can often solve many problems.

In your case, installing SP3 might fix the shell.  Plus, in general, it cant hurt (unless the install goes bad which is rare).

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at ShellExView (http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html) which allows you to see what shell extensions are registered, and enable disable them from there.  It's worth a shot!

Comment: I have used this tool, and also believe it is your best option. Look as well at PowerToy for WinXP. This too will allow you to edit what shows in the explorer pop-up menu without getting crazy with regedit.

Comment: Sorry, it is actually called TweakUI which is a Power Toy for WinXP.